# Swift, Self from AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to get Self from AnyObject?

Take this example:

```
// Superclass
class ManagedObject {
  class func findByID(id: String) -> AnyObject? {
    let objects = objectsWithPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id))
    return objects.firstObject() // Returns AnyObject
  }
}

// Subclass
class User : ManagedObject {
  class func returnFirstSelf() -> Self? {
    return findById("1") // This doesn't work because it returns AnyObject, but I need Self.
  }
}
```

If not, what is the best alternative way to ensure that when calling `User.returnFirstSelf()`, the compiler gives back a `User`, and when calling `UserSubclass.returnFirstSelf()`, it gives back a `UserSubclass`.

Comment: Unfortunately no. "'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'ManagedObject'?"

Comment: @BryanChen That results in another error, "'User' is not convertible to 'Self'"

Comment: What is the best way to implement what? Can you explain a little more informally what you're wishing to do?

Comment: I think the OP is simply trying to ensure that when calling `User.returnFirstSelf()`, the compiler tries to give back a `User`. And when calling `SomeUserSubclass.returnFirstSelf()`, it gives back a `SomeUserSubclass`.

Comment: @CraigOtis that's right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply return `User?` from your class function, if this is an option:

```
public class func returnFirstSelf() -> User? {
    if let found = findByID("1") as? User {
        return found
    }
    return nil
}
```

There's currently no way (I'm aware of) to return `Self?` with Swift as it stands. The problem is that `Self` has a somewhat... "dynamic" meaning, separate from concrete types, protocols, and even generics.  A particular example that demonstrates this is: What if you have a class `StudentUser` that extends `User`? If you tried to implement it like this:

```
class func returnFirstSelf() -> Self? {
    if let found = findById("1") as? Self { // Note the check that 'found' is a 'Self'
        return found
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then you encounter a compiler error because you cannot use `Self` outside the result of a protocol or class method. And if you try to implement it like this:

```
class func returnFirstSelf() -> Self? {
    if let found = findById("1") as? User { // Note 'User' instead of 'Self'
        return found
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then you run the risk of `Self` actually meaning `StudentUser`, and even if you pass the check that requires `found` to be a `User`, it doesn't guarantee that `found` will be a `StudentUser`. This will occur in the case that `StudentUser` does not override the method to ensure that the `as?` checks against `StudentUser`.

**The critical flaw here** in my opinion is that you cannot use the `required` keyword on class methods, requiring subclasses to override them. This would allow the compiler to ensure that any subclasses have overridden the method and provided an implementation that can guarantee type safety.

Comment: I'm telepathically pinging @RobNapier.

Comment: Thanks Craig. What if I create the subclass of `ManagedObject` called `Dog` - this would mean I have to rewrite `returnFirstSelf()` again under `Dog` to do the exact same thing, but specifically to return a `Dog` instead of something else. This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You're right. As it stands though, that is one option. The other option is simply to return `AnyObject?` from your class func, and use `if let` expressions anywhere you're using the return value to check if they are `Dog` types as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Craig Otis' answer is spot on. However, one option is to create a copy constructor. This may not work for the asker's scenario where they're inheriting from a NSManagedObject, but it should work for non-managed objects.

```
required init(user: User) {
    super.init(user: User) // or super.init() if top of inheritance.
    self.name = user.name
    self.email = user.email
    // etc.
}

class func returnFirstSelf() -> Self? {
    if let found = findById("1") { // Note the check that 'found' is a 'Self'
        return self.init(copy: found as! User)
    }
    return nil
}
```