# Why is `required` not a valid keyword on class functions in Swift?

Tags: swift

It seems that there are a few situations in which a `required` keyword on Swift class functions would be extremely beneficial, particularly due to the ability of class functions to return `Self`.

When returning `Self` from a `class func`, there are unfortunately two restrictions that make implementing said function very difficult/inhibitive:

1. You cannot use `Self` as a type check inside the function implementation, ie:

   ```
   class Donut {
       class func gimmeOne() -> Self {
           // Compiler error, 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method
           return Donut() as Self
       }
   }
   ```
2. You cannot return the actual type of the class itself, ie:

   ```
   class Donut {
       class func gimmeOne() -> Self {
           // Compiler error, 'Donut' is not convertible to 'Self'
           return Donut() 
       }
   }
   ```

**The reason** for these compiler errors is valid. If you have a `GlazedDonut` subclass that does not override this class function, it is possible that calling `GlazedDonut.gimmeOne()` will give you back a `Donut`, which *is not* a `Self`.

**It seems** this situation could be alleviated by allowing classes to specify these functions with `required`. This would ensure that any subclasses override the method and encur their own round of type checking, making sure that a `GlazedDonut` returns itself in all cases, eliminating the possibility for a `Donut` to come back.

Is there a **technical, authoritative** reason why this has not been added? I'd like to suggest it as an improvement to the Swift team, but want to ensure there isn't an obvious reason why it has been omitted, or cannot be accomplished.

The idea for this question originates here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25924224/88111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required` is generally only used on initializers, because initializers are not always inherited in Swift. Therefore, to allow you to call an initializer on a variable class (i.e. a value of metaclass type, say `Foo.Type`), you need to know that that class `Foo`, and all possible subclasses, have this initializer.

However, methods (both instance methods and class methods) are always inherited. Therefore, `required` is not necessary.

By the way, your assertion that "You cannot return the actual type of the class itself" is not true. (In fact, the error "'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method" itself says you can return the type of the class itself.) Similar to in Objective-C, you can do:

```
class Donut {
  required init() { }
  class func gimmeOne() -> Self {
    return self()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Using `self()` as the constructor works great. Further, this also allows subclasses to override the class function, while calling their own newly-added `required` initializers. This means that `GlazedDonut` can call `self()` if it wants, or it can call `self(glazeAmout : "So much. Too much?")` and make that initializer `required` for `GlazedDonut` and all subclasses of *that* particular donut type. Thank you - this problem has been bugging me for days.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a protocol to make the method 'required'

```
protocol IDonut{
    class func gimmeOne()->Donut;
}

class Donut:IDonut {
    class func gimmeOne() -> Donut {
        return Donut();
    }
}

class GlazedDonut: Donut, IDonut{
    override class func gimmeOne()->Donut{
        return GlazedDonut();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because the method no longer returns `Self`. The goal is for `GlazedDonut.gimmeOne()` to return a `GlazedDonut`.